# (React Native) Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: react-native, expo

Need help! What's wrong with my code? After running `FadeImage`, I will get this error:

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

import * as Icons from '../constants/Icons';

export default class FadeImage extends React.Component {
  state = {index:0}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.images = [
      Icons.BG_1,
      Icons.BG_2,
      Icons.BG_3,
      Icons.BG_4
    ]

    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
  }

  next() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({index: (this.state.index+1) % 4});
      this.next();
    }, 3000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.next();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
        source={this.images[this.state.index]}/>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ashish told the reason of warning is calling `this.setState` while component is already unmounted. To fix it you should just cancel timeout.

Here is code example:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

import * as Icons from '../constants/Icons';

export default class FadeImage extends React.Component {
  state = {index:0}

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.images = [
      Icons.BG_1,
      Icons.BG_2,
      Icons.BG_3,
      Icons.BG_4
    ]

    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
  }

  next() {
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({index: (this.state.index+1) % 4});
      this.next();
    }, 3000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.next();
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
        source={this.images[this.state.index]}/>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel timeout when component is destroyed. Currently, setState is being executed even when component is unloaded.